# Entity Framework - Eager mode - Is there a better way to filter child associations?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

**Reformulation of the question:**

> How to let the proxy settle for a partial loaded joint and not reloading all the child association ?

**The context :**

I have 2 entities:

> **News**
>   + Id: int
>   + Date: datetime
>
> **NewsTranslation**
>   + NewsId: id (foreign key to entity News.Id)
>   + LanguageCode: char(2)
>   + Title: nvarchar(255)
>   + Contents: nvarchar(2000)

One **News** can have as many **NewsTranslation** (one for each LanguageCode)

For example, here's the data in the database :

```
News {
 Id: 1,
 Date: "01/01/2015"
 Translations : [
    { NewsId: 1, LanguageCode: "en", Title: "Title", Contents: "English contents" },
    { NewsId: 1, LanguageCode: "fr", Title: "Titre", Contents: "French contents" }
 ]
}
```

I want to load the News entity but only with the current Language translation (for example English "en").

My code:

```
News entity     = null;
var serializer  = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

using(var context = new MyContext()) 
{
    // Disabling lazyloading (see why at the bottom of the code)
    context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

    // Load News with inner join NewsTranslation to retrieve 
    // only english language "en" 
    entity = (from news in context.News
               select new {
                   News = news,
                   NewsTranslation = from trans in news.NewsTranslation
                                     where trans.NewsId == news.Id
                                     && trans.LanguageCode == "en"
                                     select trans
               }).First()
}


//
// Serialize traverse all properties and associations.
//
// WITHOUT above "context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;" it would
// lazy load all associations NewsTranslation. Additionaly, the Context is closed so
// an exception is thrown
//
serializer.Serialize(entity)
```

This code works properly, but i am horrified to do it this way...

Is the a better way to do it without disabling LazyLoading configuration ?

---

**UPDATES:**

Based on *Brian Mains* suggestion :

**Translations first method:**

```
News entity     = null;
var serializer  = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

using(var context = new MyContext()) 
{
    entity = (from trans in context.NewsTranslation
               where trans.LanguageCode == "en"
               select trans.News).First();
}


//
// The proxy try to lazy load News.NewsTransation association,
// so an exception is thrown beacause the Context is closed
// 
//
serializer.Serialize(entity)
```

Same problem, how to let the proxy settle for the partial loaded joint ?

Comment: Sure: don't serialize entities / data model classes directly. Use a dedicated 'view model' or a 'domain model' instead... Also, that query seems to pull multiple items from the DB just to select the first one on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Well there are two ways I can see; you can use the let keyword to query the current translation (which renders a subquery in sql).  See another SO example: [Using the "let" kewword in a LINQ Query with EF 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480023/using-the-let-kewword-in-a-linq-query-with-ef-4-3)

Or, query the translations first, and include the news item, then build the model:

```
var data = from trans in news.NewsTranslation.Include("News")
                                     where trans.LanguageCode == "en"
                                     select trans;
```

The data variable contains the NewsTranslation objects, with a pre-loaded News property; if all you want out of it is news, you could then change the query to:

```
var data = from trans in news.NewsTranslation
                                     where trans.LanguageCode == "en"
                                     select trans.News;
```

I'm not sure what kind of LINQ this produces, whether it is a simple join; you can always join to the news entity and select that directly instead of using the news object.

EDIT: if you only want the first object, just do:

```
var results = (from trans in context.NewsTranslation
               where trans.LanguageCode == "en"
               select trans.News).First();
```

Don't use `ToList()` and don't use `Select()`; it doesn't get you anything.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my question. I just tested to query the translations first. I'm facing the same problem: when retrieving the News.NewsTranslation, the proxy try to lazy load the full associations. I'm trying your second method with let keyword...

Comment: Edited.  Just use First() on the query; that should get you the same result.